# Why $F^S$ represents set of functions from S to F?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

This is a definition from the book "Linear Algebra Done Right"

$F^S$ Notation

> - If $S$ is a set, then $F^S$ denotes the set of functions from $S$ to $F$.
> - And $F^S$ is a vector space with following addition and scalar multiplication.
> - $\forall f, g \in F^S, \ \exists f + g \in F^S$ is a function defined by
>   $$\forall x \in S, \ (f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x)$$
> - $\forall \lambda \in F, \ \forall f \in F^S, \ \exists \lambda f \in F^S$ is the function defined by
>   $$\forall x \in S, \ (\lambda f )(x) = \lambda f(x)$$

Here $F$ denotes a field.

My Question is why $F^S$, I don't understand the intuition behind this notation. Everything work perfectly fine even if we say

> Let $X$ be set of all function from $S$ to $F$.

It feels like an arbitrary choice, why $F^S$? Is there a deeper meaning or some historical reason?

Sorry if the question is stupid.

Comment: I *think* the reason is that you can have any choice of $a\in S$ being mapped to any $b\in F$.  This is similar to exponents in that $m^n$ means we are multiplying the "options" of the number $m$ by itself one time for each of the values up to $n$.  Note if $F$ and $S$ are finite then $|F^S|=|F|^{|S|}$. And furthermore if we use set notation concept of natural numbers so that $n = \{0,1,2,....,n-1\}$ then $n^m$ literally *is* the number of functions from $\{0,1,...,m-1\} \to \{0,1,2,....n-1\}$.  And we have bijection for the functions themselves to integer $n^m=\{0,1,2,.....,n^m-1\}$.

Comment: Thank you, totally makes sense, I'm always keep forgetting that numbers are sets!

Comment: Another point of view: $\mathbb R^n$ is, literally, the set of length $n$ sequences $(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ of real numbers, that is to say the set of functions $x : \{1,2,\ldots,n\} \to \mathbb R$. Although this is not quite in accord with the modern set-theoretical definition under which we have the equation $n = \{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$, it is perhaps a more historically accurate justification for the $F^S$ notation in general.

Comment: .... and the concept of $A\times B = \{(a,b)|a\in A, b\in B\}$. Why the heck do we use "TIMES" for that notation???... well, because if we consider counting the number of such pairs.... And so $A^3 = A\times A\times A$ well now we have Lee Mosher's comment above.  How is it a set of *functions*? Well, it is the set of $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ triplets. and each triplet is a mapping of $1\to a_2, 2\to a_2, 3\to a_3$ which is nothing more or less than a function for $(1,2,3)\to A$ so $A^3$ is *literally* a collection functions from $\{1,2,3\} \to A$.

Comment: Actually.... I have to say Lee Mosher's comment says what I wanted to in my answer... but *much* more succinctly and clearly!... "I'm always keep forgetting that numbers are sets"  You don't really need to have that in the fore of your mind but this concepts of enumerations might make these strange notations seem more intuitive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear with me....

Are you familiar with the concept of set foundation of the natural numbers?

It is that $0= \emptyset$

$1 = \{0\} = \{\emptyset\}$.

$2 = \{0,1\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$

$3 = \{0,1,2\} = \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$ and so on.

I'm actually a little rusty on how exactly addition and muliplication of integers as sets are defined but... I trust it is consistently done and I could look it up if I wanted to.

Now in set theory *everything* is a set and a function from set $A$ to set $B$ is a subset of the set $A\times B= \{(a,b)|a\in A, b\in B\}$ which is a set of ordered pairs and ordered pairs are sets.  I confess I do not remember exactly *how* an ordered pair as an unordered set is defined or how a function as a set is defined. But again I trust is is done some way consistently.

Now note.  If $n= \{0,1,2,3,...,n-1\}$ and $m=\{0,1,2,3,.....,m-1\}$ are sets.  Then if we consider the numbers for function $f_i:m \to n$ we realize that to count the number of functions we have for each $a \in \{0,1,2,....,m-1\}$ we have $f(a)\in \{0,1,2,3,...,n-1\}$ and we have $n$ choices for what $f(a)$ might be.  We consider and for another $b\in \{0,1,2,...,m-1\}; b\ne a$ we have $n$ choices of what $f(b)$ might be.  That is $n \times n = n^2$ choices for what $f(a),f(b)$ might be.  To count the total number of choices each of the $m$ values of $\{0,1,....,m-1\}$ are mapped to $n$ possible choices of $\{0,1,....,n-1\}$ so we have $\underbrace{n\times n \times n ....\times n}= n^m$ possible functions from $m \to n$.

That means we have a bijection from $\{f: f:m \to n\}$ and $n^m = \{0,1,2,.....,n^m-1\}$.  So $|\{f: f:m \to n\}| = |n^m| =n^m$.

Now as I said... I don't remember (actually I never really learned) the exact *method* in which the concept of function is defined in the set foundation model where "everything is a set" but I suspect (in fact idea be surprised if it weren't) that the actual set that represents the set of functions is exactly the same as the set $n^m$.

[for example  If we had $2= \{0,1\}$ and $3=\{0,1,2\}$ there are $3^2$ functions that map $2\to 3$.  The are $(0\to 0, 1\to 0),(0\to 0, 1\to 1),(0\to 0, 1\to 2),(0\to 1, 1\to 0),(0\to 1,1\to 1), (0\to 1, 1\to 2), (0\to 2,1\to 0),(0\to 2, 1\to 1),(0\to 2, 1\to 2)$.

[The set $3^2 = 9 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9\} = \{0\cdot 3+0,0\cdot 3+1, 0\cdot 3 + 2, 1\cdot 3+0, 1\cdot 3 + 1, 1\cdot 3 + 2, 2\cdot 3 + 0, 2\cdot 3 + 1, 2\cdot 3 + 2\}$.  So if we define the function $f_i:2\to 3 = (0\to a, 1\to b) = a\cdot 3 + b$ then we indeed *do* have that $\{f|f: 3\to 2\} = \{a\cdot 3 + b| a,b\in 3\}= \{0,...,8\}=9 = 3^2$ and that $3^2$ *does* equal the set of functions from $2\to 3$.]

[Now I suspect that isn't *exactly* how functions are defined but I suspect it is something quite analogous].

In any event, we can easily verify that $|\{f:S\to F\}| = |F|^{|S|}$ so at the very least it makes for a convenient shorthand notation.

As an aside you have probably seen the notation $|\mathbb R| = 2^{\mathbb N}$ meaning that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable whereas $|\mathbb Z| = |\mathbb N|$ means $\mathbb Z$ is countable.  This actually means that for any map for $\mathbb N \to \{0,1\}$ we which can be represented by a countably *infinite* string of zeros, and ones which can represent the binary expansion of a real number means the cardinality of the set of countably infinite binary strings is equal to the cardinality of the real numbers... which Cantor proved.

This notation seems odd at first but it makes sense if you think combinatorial about mapping elements from one set to another will result on $F^S$ possible mappings.

Comment: This isn't how functions are defined, but this is quite elegant. I never thought about functions like that. Thank you. 

"[for example  If we had $2= \{0,1\}$ and $3=\{0,1,2\}$ there are $3^2$ functions that mapp $2\to 3$.  The are $(0\to 0, 1\to 0),(0\to 0, 1\to 1),(0\to 0, 1\to 2),(0\to 1, 1\to 0),(0\to 1,1\to 1), (0\to 1, 1\to 2), (0\to 2,1\to 0),(0\to 2, 1\to 1),(0\to 2, 1\to 2)$"

Comment: Well, functions are defined as the subsets of the cross-product where each element of the domain set is represented as the first element of an ordered pair *exactly* once in the set.... How "ordered pairs" are defined in a set structure, I'm not sure nor am I sure how the requirement "each element of the domain set is represented as... " is stipulated.  But I'm sure it can and is somehow consistently done.

Comment: If I remember correctly, ordered pairs are defined as $(a , b) = \{a,\{b\}\}$  and $(b, a) = \{b,\{a\}\}$

Answer (score 5):

I think your skepticism is very understandable! But here's the key fact that I think justifies that notation: if $F$ and $S$ are finite sets with $f$ and $s$ elements, respectively, then the number of functions from $S$ to $F$ (namely, the number of elements of $F^S$) equals $f^s$.

Comment: For those curious: This is the tl;dr of fleablood's answer.